# How do I pass in event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The javascript code is like below.

```
var ADDRESS = {
    checkit : function(element){
    if(event.target.className == "delete"){
        doSomethingweird();
    } else {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

and the calling function looks something like below.

```
<div onclick="ADDRESS.checkit(this);">
    <div class="delete">del</div>
</div>
```

Apparently, only input 'this' gets passed in, but I want to also pass in the event such that I can use it to find out the event.target.className.
(Above code works in Chrome, but not in IE so far, because IE does not seem to recognize event)
How should I change `ADDRESS.addressbook_clicked(this);` so that event also gets passed in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML should be

```
<div onclick="ADDRESS.checkit(this, event||window.event);">
    <div class="delete">del</div>
</div>
```

Now the event element is also being passed to your event handler.

**Warning**
This is old style event handling, most people nowadays use non-obtrusive event handling which decouples your JS and your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Bind your handler in the usual jQuery manner:

```
<div id="x">
    <div class="delete">del</div>
</div>
```

And:

```
$('#x').click(ADDRESS.checkit);
```

Then, change your `ADDRESS` to this:

```
var ADDRESS = {
    checkit : function(event){
        // And if you need your old "element", look in "this" instead.
        if(event.target.className == "delete"){
            doSomethingweird();
        } else {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
};
```

That should solve your cross-browser problems and it is the standard jQuery approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you can garantee the structure of your HTML then you could do something like this:

```
var ADDRESS = {
    checkit : function(element){
    if($(this).children(".delete").length > 0){
        doSomethingweird();
    } else {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using jQuery here, if the OP were using jQuery, they probably wouldn't even ask this question

Comment: This question is tagged with jQuery?

Comment: True, but setting event handlers from HTML and then using jQuery within the handlers seems so backwards! You could suggest the best way to do it with jQuery, but a mixture is not the best suggestion.

Comment: Your probably correct. I just started with jQuery a few months ago. I like mu's answer. That seems more in the spirit of jQuery.